# Typeahead in a Model return empty value to form input field

Tags: javascript, php, typeahead.js

I create a table with a button. When a user switch the button it will open a Bootstrap-Modal.
Inside the Modal is a form wite a typeahed select field. The list works and all items are selectable.

My Problem: 
If i select a item it shows on form on post the return value (PHP $_POST) are empty.

My js code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/testPost',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            //data: 'query=' + query,
            data: 'query=' + $('#contactName').val(),

            success: function(data)
            {
                var results = data.map(function(item) {
                    //var someItem = { contactname: item.ContactName, telephone: item.Telephone, email: item.Email };
                    var someItem = { contactname: item.ContactName, id: item.id };
                    console.log(item);
                    return JSON.stringify(someItem.contactname);
                });

                return process(results);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    updater: function(item) {
        // This may need some tweaks as it has not been tested
        var obj = JSON.parse(item);
        return item;
    }
});
```

});

php json

```
    $return_arr[] = array("id" => "1", "ContactName" => "Dooome");
$return_arr[] = array("id" => "2", "ContactName" => "Caa");
$return_arr[] = array("id" => "3", "ContactName" => "Veee");
$return_arr[] = array("id" => "4", "ContactName" => "Moo");
$return_arr[] = array("id" => "5", "ContactName" => "Reee");
#$return_arr[] = array("value" => "Dooome");

header("Content-Type: application/json");
print_r(json_encode($return_arr));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want select in typeahead input `.val()` not working, you get value with: `$('#contactName').typeahead('val')`, this way you get value
 of input for sending in data of Post Ajax

Look at [the documentation of typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md)